# Get index of active slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to get the index of the active slide and store it as an integer so that I can call functions and pass in the integer.

I have code that displays the index of the integer in a MsgBox. And yet, when I try to store the index as an integer, nothing happens.

This code shows an integer of the index.

```vb
Sub SlideIDX()
MsgBox "The slide index of the current slide is:" & _
  activePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.slideIndex
End Sub
```

This code makes the attempt of storing an integer.

```vb
Sub slidePassInTest()
Dim passInteger As Integer
Set passInteger = activePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.slideIndex
MsgBox (passInteger)
End Sub
```

I also tried not using Set.

Comment: You use SET for objects, and as near as I can tell, your code should work if you use passInteger = {etc} rather than Set passInteger = {etc}.  And it does work here.  You should Dim passInteger as a Long, since that's what SlideIndex returns, but that won't change the way it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method always works for me:

```
Sub SlideIDX()

Dim currentSlide As Slide

Dim slideIndex as Long

Set currentSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
slideIndex = currentSlide.SlideIndex

End Sub
```